# Custom aws_lb_listener for aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment with Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a working aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment in Terraform and I'd like to add HTTP to HTTPS redirect to it.

I've created a `aws_lb_listener` to do this and would like to set the `load_balancer_arn` to point to my Elastic BeanStalk application.

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "default" {
  depends_on          = ["aws_route53_record.cert_dns_validate_record"]
  name                = "${var.app_env_name}"
  application         = "${var.app_env_name}"
  solution_stack_name = "${var.solution_stack_name}"
  ...
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "http" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${element(aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.default.load_balancers, 0)}"
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type = "redirect"

    redirect {
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to do this I get the following error however:

```
Error: Error creating LB Listener: ValidationError: 'awseb-e-p-AWSEBLoa-1E9JXK93ULR1I' must be in ARN format
    status code: 400, request id: d38933a0-c1e3-43fc-ac22-10659beb86b6

  on ../modules/elasticbeanstalk/environment/main.tf line 420, in resource "aws_lb_listener" "http":
 420: resource "aws_lb_listener" "http" {
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Here's my full .tf file: https://pastebin.com/KhakuvQJ

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** manipulate Elastic Beanstalk environment like this. That can cause issues that you may even have time to fix. I highly recommend to use first `elastic_beanstalk_configuration_template` resource to manipulate the default Elastic Beanstalk configuration you have. Then, you can include template you have in `aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment`. End of the day, Elastic Beanstalk is just a CloudFormation snippet.

Please read [`Setting`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elastic_beanstalk_configuration_template.html#setting) option and list of [configuration options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html).